# ui-router won't let me go back to resolved state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to call a service on route changes that will check access and if access is `true` will open the route, if not, will go to the settings route

app.js:

```
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            resolve: {
                access: function(AuthService) {

                    return AuthService.getAccess();
                }
            }
        })
```

In my homeCtrl:

```
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $timeout, $state, UserService, GroupService, SiteService, HomeService, AuthService, access) {


    // Check access: if true init route, else go to settings
    if(access) {
        Collections.init();
    } else {
        $state.go('settings');
    }

});
```

If I switch to another state that doesn't have any resolve, I can't switch back to the home page, the button just doesn't do anything now.

Also, instead of handling the re-direction to settings from the homeCtrl, how would I do this from the resolve, wouldn't that be a better approach

Using Angular 1.5.x and UI-Router 0.2.18

EDIT:

Before I wasn't using resolve but instead

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            AuthService.getAccess().then(function (access) {
                if (!access && toState.name !== "settings") {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    toastr.warning('Your trial has expired');
                    $state.go('settings');
                }
            });
        });
```

What I noticed however is that my UI will load at sometimes before the authService.getAccess() was done, so I was hitting a race condition.

I moved to resolved since that gave me better control over the application flow.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to what you did - add a callback to each transition start.

```
const app = angular.module('yourApplication');

app.run([
    '$state', '$transitions', 'authManager',
    function ($state, $transitions, authManager) {

        $transitions.onStart({from: ''}, function (transition) {
           const to = transition.$to();
           const routeName = to.name;

           if(!authManager.isAuthorizedRoute(routeName)) {
               // here you can substitute login with any other state
               // returning another target will break the transition and direct to another state
               return transition.router.stateService.target('login');
           }

           // if nothing is returned the transition will continue
        }
    }

]);
```

EDIT:

Since `getAccess` is executed asynchronous - there is another solution:

1.Create a parent state, put resolve your resolve there

```
$stateProvider.state('authorized', {
    resolve: {
       access: function(AuthService) {
          return AuthService.getAccess();
       }
    }
})
```

2.Define parent state on your state

```
.state('yourSTATE', {
     .....
     parent:      'authorized',
     ....
 })
```

3.Handle onSuccess of the $transitions (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2946) to access resolved data and then decide whether transition should success and redirect to another target

```
app.run([
    '$transitions',
    function ($transitions) {

        $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
            var hasAccess = transition.getResolveValue('access');

            if(!hasAccess) {
               return transition.router.stateService.target('login');
            }
        });
     }
]);
```

Comment: See my edit, I had something like this before but I would race race conditions.So I moved to resolve to ensure `getAccess()` finished before the state loaded.

Comment: yes, since `getAccess` is working asynchronously, won't work in this case. I'll edit a solution in a bit

Comment: @Batman, updated the solution - please check it and let me know, whether it helped or not.